# How to make wider the glossaries style super

Tags: glossaries

I am using the glossary style "super" as follows:

```
\usepackage[nopostdot,  style=super, nonumberlist]{glossaries} 

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name=latex,
    description={Is a markup language specially suited 
    for scientific documents, Is a markup language specially suited 
    for scientific documents}
}
```

And I am getting this result:

[image: Screenshot]

I would like to remove the blank space on the right, making the description wider, but I don't know how could I modify this. I guess I could create a new style but I want it to be like the "super" style, but wider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the width used by the `supertabular` :

`\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{<length>}`

Default = `0.6\hsize`

(Therefore `\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{\hsize}` is equivalent to

`\usepackage[nopostdot,  nosuper, nonumberlist]{glossaries}` )

Using `\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{0.75\hsize}`

[image: d]

This is the complete code. Compile as `pdflatex` + `makeglossaries` + `pdflatex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nopostdot,  style=super, nonumberlist]{glossaries}  

\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{0.75\hsize}% added <<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{showframe}% only to show the margins

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{shopfloor}
{
    name=shop floor,
    description={The part of a workshop or factory where production as distinct from administrative work is carried out}
}

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name=latex,
    description={Is a markup language specially suited 
        for scientific documents. Is a markup language specially suited 
        for scientific documents}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \gls{shopfloor}  
    
    \gls{latex}
            
    \printglossaries        
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is exactly that, thank you!